# compare the system time and NSDatePicker time

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsdate

I have to compare the system time and the time chosen in NSDatePicker field. If they are equal need to do some actions. What is the best way to compare the time?

Comment: To what resolution? Days, seconds, minutes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answers your question literally:

```
NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
NSDate *pickerDate = [pickerDate date]; // where pickerDate is your NSDatePicker object

if ([currentDate isEqualToDate:pickerDate]) {
    // do stuff
}
```

But that's not a very likely situation because `isEqualToDate` is [sub-second precise](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDate/isEqualToDate%3a), so it's not likely a user will choose the exact date/time when fiddling with an NSDatePicker. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm sorry but I mean that comparison will running until the dates becomes equal